# What type of design is called when categories of catalog cut through on the right side?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, print-production, terminology

I need a template to design something like this, but I don't know the proper term for it.

Does anyone know what this type of design is called, when categories cut through on the right side of a catalogue ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These can be called index tabs, index dividers or cut-out tabs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a step tab design. Since there seems to be 11 tabs, they're called 1/11th cut, or bank of 11. The tabs themselves are usually 1/2" wider than the pages they're separating. So if the page is 8-1/2 X 11, then the tab is 9 X 11. The cover should be as wide as the tabs so the tabs don't get bent when the cover is closed - similar to the image you show.

The stock for the tabs is heavier than the stock for the pages, usually a cover weight.

These are stock dies so if you contact your vendor, he'd be able to provide a template. You can also find some stock designs online - here's a sample set of different banks:

https://blanksusa.com/design-templates/tab-divider-templates

Any additional info you need, stay in touch.